# Capturing Powershell output in C# after Pipeline.Invoke throws

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-1.0

I'm running a Powershell test script from a C# application. The script can fail due to a bad cmdlet which causes pipe.Invoke() to throw an exception.

I'm able to capture all the information I need about the exception, but I'd like to be able to display the script's output up to that point. I haven't had any luck since results appears to be null when an exception is thrown.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

```
m_Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
m_Runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipe = m_Runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipe.Commands.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(ScriptFile));
pipe.Commands.Add("Out-String");
try {
   results = pipe.Invoke();
}
catch (System.Exception)
{
   m_Runspace.Close();
   // How can I get to the Powershell output that comes before the exception?
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to implement our own PSHost to handle PowerShell's output. The initial information for this came from http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/07/06/windows-powershell-through-ironruby-writing-a-custom-pshost.aspx in the "Building a custom PS host" section.

In my case it did require using a custom PSHostRawUserInterface as well.

Here's the quick overview of what was done. I've only listed the function I actually implimented, but there's many that are just contain throw new NotImplementedException();

```
private class myPSHost : PSHost
{
   (Same as what the above link mentions)
}
private class myPSHostUI : PSHostUserInterface
{
   private myPSHostRawUI rawui = new myPSHostRawUI();

   public override void Write // all variations
   public override PSHostRawUserInterface RawUI { get { return rawui; } }

}
private class myPSHostRawUI : PSHostRawUserInterface
{
   public override ConsoleColor ForegroundColor
   public override ConsoleColor BackgroundColor
   public override Size BufferSize
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this is helpful. I am guessing you are running V1. This V2 approach doesn't throw and prints the result:

```
Hello World
67 errors

string script = @"
  'Hello World'
  ps | % {
    $_.name | out-string1
  }
";

PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

powerShell.AddScript(script);
var results = powerShell.Invoke();

foreach (var item in results)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}

if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} errors", powerShell.Streams.Error.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. The easiest way to get output when pipe.Invoke() throws an exception is to use [Invoke(IEnumerable input, IList output)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182456(v=vs.85).aspx)

Example shows how to get all output, error, waning etc. in the correct order

**PowerShell script**

```
Write-Output "Hello world" 
Write-Error "Some error"
Write-Warning "Some warning"
throw "Some exception"
```

**C#**

```
List<string> RunLog = new List<string>(); 

using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell psInstance = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())

{
    psInstance.AddScript(_Script);

psInstance.Streams.Error.DataAdded += (sender, args) =>
{
    ErrorRecord err = ((PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)sender)[args.Index];
    RunLog.Add($"ERROR: {err}");
};

psInstance.Streams.Warning.DataAdded += (sender, args) =>
{
    WarningRecord warning = ((PSDataCollection<WarningRecord>)sender)[args.Index];
    RunLog.Add($"WARNING: {warning}");
};

... etc ...

var result = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
result.DataAdded += (sender, args) =>
{
    PSObject output = ((PSDataCollection<PSObject>)sender)[args.Index];
    RunLog.Add($"OUTPUT: {output}");
};

try
{
    psInstance.Invoke(null, result);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    RunLog.Add($"EXCEPTION: {ex.Message}");
}                                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the objects before the exception and keep using a pipeline instead of a Powershell instance you can use `Pipeline.Output.DataReady` or `Pipeline.Error.DataReady` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipelinereader-1.dataready?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). Here is an example redirecting all streams to default output (using `MergeMyResults`) and listening to the default pipeline output:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Output.DataReady += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    PSObject obj = ((PipelineReader<PSObject>)sender).Read();
    Console.WriteLine("OUTPUT: "+obj.ToString());
};
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
pipeline.Commands[pipeline.Commands.Count-1]
    .MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.All, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: "+ ex.Message);
}
```