# Running a powershell command in C# errors with, "Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, powershell, exchange-server

I have an application that I use to run Exchange Powershell commands inside C# code like below.  This is an example of the relevant lines I use to run the powershell command.

```
            RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException snapInException = null;

        //load Exchange shell
        rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapInException); 
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);

        //open runspace
        runSpace.Open();

        //setup pipeline
        Pipeline pipeLine = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
        String sScript = "get-mailbox -identity 'rj'";

        //add script to pipeline
        pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(sScript);

        //run the script
        pipeLine.Invoke();
        pipeLine.Dispose();
```

This code works perfect in all cases until now.  the script I am trying to run instead of the one above is to set the RetentionPolicy for a mailbox.  The script I am trying to run looks like this:

Set-Mailbox -Identity 'rj' -RetentionPolicy 'Main Campus Retention Policy'

When I run this in powershell itself it works perfectly but when I try to run it using the code below I get the error, "Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it."

From this error, it almost seems like the command that runs in C# cannot run the RetentionPolicy command but that doesn't make much sense.  I have Googled this and tried everything suggested but no luck.

If anyone knows why this is happening, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If that command would normally prompt for confirmation then you will need to either:

- Set `-Confirm:$false` as a parameter (and possibly `-Force` as well)
- Set `$ConfirmPreference = "None"` before calling Set-Mailbox (and possibly `-Force` too)
- Create a Host and implement the Confirm functionality ;-)

Comment: You nailed it with the -Force.  It worked perfect once I added that.  Thanks for the help, that completes these requirements.  Awesome!

Comment: @Kiquenet, I believe the simple answer is just to set the sScript that he's executing to: `Set-Mailbox -Identity 'rj' -RetentionPolicy 'Main Campus Retention Policy' -Confirm:$false -Force`

Comment: Interesting. I'll try out the -Force approach. Any ways, if you are still interested, here is the same for implementing the interfaces for PSHost, Pshostuserinterface and pshostrawuserinterface. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233640/capturing-powershell-output-in-c-sharp-after-pipeline-invoke-throws

Comment: `-Confirm:$false` did the trick for `Add-RecipientPermission`, too. Now I can finally add `SendAs` permissions. Thanks.