# Possible to automate exchange 2003 mailbox creation with asp.net c# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, exchange-server

I wrote a asp.net C# website that creates users in active directory but I would also like to automate the mailbox creation as well. The exchange server is 2003 and I would need to automate creating the mailbox, the store the mailbox is located in, and the mailbox quota policy for that user. Does anyone know if this is possible or does the exchange server have to be 2007/2010? If it is possible could you point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: in exchange 2003, you can use powershell, although some cmdlet may not exist. you can call powershell from c# code to do these. there are many samples of how to get powershell run from c#, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233640/capturing-powershell-output-in-c-sharp-after-pipeline-invoke-throws

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a download. You have a small exe that runs and sets up Outlook. It would allow for more freedom.

Comment: I will consider this but I will still have the same drawbacks of exchange 2003's lack of powershell integration