# Using C# to execute PowerShell script with command line args using V2 methods

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing an C# application which will need to execute Powershell scripts with command line arguments and retrieve the output (aka what I would expect to see in the output window of PowerShell ISE - including exception information)

I have found numerous code examples of how to accomplish this task using PowerShell V1 objects. These examples create runspaces, pipelines, etc. (ex [Execute PowerShell Script from C# with Commandline Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments))

I have seen a few scant references to a different way to do this using PowerShell V2. (the top answer here: [Capturing Powershell output in C# after Pipeline.Invoke throws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233640/capturing-powershell-output-in-c-sharp-after-pipeline-invoke-throws)) Using V2 seems **much** simpler. No messing around with runspaces, piplines or any of that. Something like this:

```
PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

powerShell.AddScript(script);
var results = powerShell.Invoke();
```

Are there any good working examples out there of using PowerShell V2 objects to execute scripts from within C# code? Is there any known good documentation of the PowerShell V2 (or even V3) objects and best practices on how to use them? Offical docs from Microsoft like there ought to be? A good book or site which breaks down the System.Management.Automation assembly piece by piece?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question here. It looks like the right approach would be for my application to function as a PowerShell Host

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx

Use of PowerShell V2 objects is defined here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx