# Run script file on remote server

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, scripting, remote-access

I'm tasked with automating an internal process.
This process involves first being logged on a remote server (A).
From server A, a user would connect to Remote Server (B).

Once authenticated onto Server B, the users need to perform three main tasks:

1. Change a file name in a local directory.
2. Open command prompt and perform "iisreset"
3. Open Internet explorer to ensure the connection with IIS is re-established.

I've used some sample code form a post on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET) to make all the remote desktop connections and it's working without issue.
The codes uses the [ActiveX MSTSC Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383022(v=vs.85).aspx).

My question lies in the steps outlined above.
Once connected to Server B, how do I pragmatically perform these operations.
Right now, We do have an internal script which performs these steps.
To execute the script, the user must log onto Server B and manually run the Script.

If it's possible to make the connections and to execute the script pragmatically this would be a solution. If for some reason this is not possible, I would need to perform the three steps pragmatically as a solution instead.

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Does this need to happen at a specific time?  Could you just have a process running on server B that checks if it needs to run the script?

Comment: No, there is no time interval to the process.
It happens on the fly as it is a support services for a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Powershell [New-PSSession](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849717.aspx).

Excerpt from Microsoft Site:

> The **New-PSSession** cmdlet creates a Windows PowerShell session
>   (PSSession) on a local or remote computer. When you create a
>   PSSession, Windows PowerShell establishes a persistent connection to
>   the remote computer.

Save the following to a PS1 file:

```
Write-Output "Please supply your credential for <insert server name>"
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter credential for <insert server name>"

Try
{
    $s1 = new-pssession -computername <fully qualified domain name (FQDN)> q -credential $cred -Authentication Credssp
}
Catch [system.exception]
{
    "Your account doesn't have access to <insert server name>"
    "Not sure what permission are really require on the server"
    "When I have a chance, need to test with the other developers"
}

# If you wanted to set a path you could do this
$env:Path = $env:Path + ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"

# Create the command we want to execute on the remote server
# This block can contain anything you do at command prompt
$block = {
dir
cd "\Foo"
.\Bar.bat
}

if ($s1)
{
    Invoke-Command $block -session $s1
    remove-pssession $s1
}

Start-Sleep 5
```

Once you have a script, you can model you C# application after it following the example from [PowerShell Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response.
I'll look into running a PS1 file from a C# program.
The requirements state the program must be built on a .NET platform since it has some GUI components and extra features.

Comment: My script is just showing what the powershell script would look like.  Then to run it from c# executable, you could do the following: [Using C# to execute PowerShell script with command line args using V2 methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867636/using-c-sharp-to-execute-powershell-script-with-command-line-args-using-v2-metho)

Answer (score 0):

You may use psexec to run scripts on another machine. It comes with the sysinternals suite. 
Command would seem like below: 
psexec \\serverB <local path of the script>